# Where can I find a full list of Asp.NET Core web.config environment variables?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

In Asp.NET Core web applications, you can set environment variables such as ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT and COMPLUS_ForceENC to modify the behavior of the application:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" hostingModel="inprocess" disableStartUpErrorPage="true">
  <environmentVariables>
    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
    <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
  </environmentVariables>
</aspNetCore>
```

Where can I find a full list of all the possible environment variables that are accepted? Preferably for Asp.NET Core 3.1.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the possible values and their metadata should be listed here:

Current: [ASP.NET Core 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-6.0#host-configuration-values)

Previous LTS: [ASP.NET Core 3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1#host-configuration-values-2)